# Disable status bar in full screen android application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-10.0

I'm using an Android 10 tablet and currently developing a full screen application. Currently it is possible for the user to pull down the status bar and access wifi, bluetooth etc...

Is it possible to completely disable the status bar?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with your app because the system controls that. The only solution for this I think it could be if you are using Kiosk mode, but I never used one so I am not sure if users are still able to access some of the status bar options.

Comment: I'll read up about Kiosk mode, thanks. 

I've seen some comments about it being possible if you root the tablet/phone. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: A workaround is to write your app as a Lock Screen Device App.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the statusBar while your app is running. but, you user can still drag the screen down and interact with wi-fi, Bluetooth, Mobile data...

Comment: Of course it should, this is not even an answer